# Looping through dictionary of objects in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm writing code to instantiate a form that shows one record in each instance. I have functions to open and close instances using a dictionary but now I need to check whether a record is already opened.

Dictionaries and collections only allow you to store pairs of data (key/item) so created a class with two properties: form object and the opened record id. I store key and this object in a dictionary.

Now I want to check if a record id is already opened so I have to loop trough the dictionary checking the record id (servicioid in code below) property of the item.

Class module:

```
Private propFormulario As Form
Private propServicioId As Long

Public Property Let FormObj(frmFormObj As Form)
Set propFormulario = frmFormObj
End Property

Public Property Get FormObj() As Form
Set FormObj = propFormulario
End Property

Public Property Let servicioid(lngServicioId As Long)
propServicioId = lngServicioId
End Property

Public Property Get servicioid() As Long
servicioid = propServicioId
End Property
```

Open and close instances:

```
Public dicFormServicios As New Dictionary   

Public Sub AbrirServicio(lngServicioId As Long)

Dim ServicioAbierto As clsServiciosAbiertos

Set ServicioAbierto = New clsServiciosAbiertos

ServicioAbierto.FormObj = New Form_servicios2
ServicioAbierto.servicioid = lngServicioId

dicFormServicios.Add CStr(ServicioAbierto.FormObj.hwnd), ServicioAbierto
ServicioAbierto.FormObj.visible = True

End Sub

Public Sub CerrarServicio(InstanciaHwnd As Long)

If dicFormServicios.Exists(CStr(InstanciaHwnd)) Then
   dicFormServicios.Remove CStr(InstanciaHwnd)
End If

End Sub
```

My question is how do I loop trough the dictionary and how do I check an ID is in the servicioid property of any item.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Show us the code you already tried to solve your problem/request.

Comment: Shouldn't`Public Property Let FormObj`be a property set (as you set an object)?

Comment: To loop through a dictionary create a variant then ```for each yourvariant in dicFormServicios.keys```

Comment: @ComputerVersteher maybe, sorry this is my first vba class, I'll give it a try. thank you!

Comment: No need for excuses! I It's never to late to start with OOPP  You can gain huge  knowledge improvement on that by reading  the [RubberduckVBA-Blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/08/about-class-modules/)

Comment: @UnhandledException Sorry, my question is how do I loop trough the dictionary and how do I check an ID is in the servicioid property of any item.

Comment: That comment should be your web-search

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of a dictionary.  The idea with a dictionary is that you don't loop through it at all - you reference it like a dictionary, giving the name of the object that you're looking for which returns the definition.  In your case I would use the ID as the key and the form as the returned value.

Comment: There are [lots of posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dictionary+vba) about this.

Comment: @Paul I think you could be right. Maybe I'm making things complicated. Maybe I don't need to create a class and just store the ID as key. I will try to reference to the form hwnd trough the form property if I need it.

Comment: You know that the forms are already in a collection called `Forms` - you can reference them using the `Forms!["formName"]` or `Forms![0..n]` syntax (I can't remember if there's an exclamation mark in there or not, but worth a try!). :o)

Answer (score 0):

My VBA is a bit rusty, so you're going to want to do something along the lines of...

```
dicFormServicios.Add myForm.FormId, myForm
```

Then to recover a value try...

```
myReturnForm = dicFormServicios.Item("SomeFormName")
```

Details here...

- [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)
- [Whether a value exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exists-method)
- [Recover an item from the dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-property-dictionary-object)

(The Dictionary reference above is very useful, but really...) All of the objects that you need are already there. You can reference an object directly from the `Forms` collection using either an index number...

```
Set myForm = Forms![0]
```

...or by using the form's name...

```
Set myForm = Forms!["myFormName"]
```

*(Such a long time since I've done any of this stuff!)*

Comment: Access opens only one instance for any form or report. What I'm doing is skipping access instanciating and making my own collection of forms so I can instantiate the same form infinite times. I took the idea from http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html

Comment: @rednoise - Ah! Yes - very true (it's all coming back to me!).  Oh! The horror!